# Parsing HTML Document with JSOUP, can't select table node?

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, html-table, jsoup

I've already looked into several Stack Overflow topics with similar questions.

I have the following problem: I have a simple html page, downloaded and saved locally as .html File, I am parsing it with JSoup to read the content of that table. Unfortunately when I look for my table with .select("table") it returns me no Elements. Hence I have debugged it, what I could notice is... my body node has one childnode, which appears to be solely String, and thus I assume I can't find any table node?

Can anyone help me out please?

Here is my code snippet:

```
   for (Element table : doc.select("table.creditsuisse")) {
        for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
            for (Element tds : row.select("td")){
                for(Element link : row.select("href")){
                    System.out.println(link.text());
                }
                System.out.println(tds.text());
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is how my input File looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table class="creditsuisse" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th style="width:170px;">Funktion</th>
        <th style="width:180px;">
        Amtsdauer (Seit)        </th>
        <th style="width:130px;">Alter (Geburtsdatum)</th>
        <th style="width:45px;">Neuigkeit</th>
      </tr>
            <tr>

          <td>
            <a onclick="document.location='/u/p/al_thani_jassim_hamad_j_j-9293792/credit_suisse_ag_CH-020.3.923.549-1.htm'" href="/u/p/al_thani_jassim_hamad_j_j-9293792/credit_suisse_ag_CH-020.3.923.549-1.htm">Al-Thani Jassim Hamad J.J.</a> *&nbsp;<br>

          </td>

          <td>
                          VR-Mitglied           
          </td>
                    <td><a onclick="document.location='http://www.moneyhouse.ch/u/pub/credit_suisse_ag_CH-020.3.923.549-1.htm#28.06.2010'" href="/u/pub/credit_suisse_ag_CH-020.3.923.549-1.htm#28.06.2010">2 Jahre (28.06.2010)</a></td>
                  <td>-</td>
          <td align="center"></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>

          <td>
            <a onclick="document.location='/u/p/albers_franz-4438178/credit_suisse_ag_CH-020.3.923.549-1.htm'" href="/u/p/albers_franz-4438178/credit_suisse_ag_CH-020.3.923.549-1.htm">Albers Franz</a> *&nbsp;<br>

          </td>

          <td>
                          VR-Mitglied           
          </td>
                    <td><a onclick="document.location='http://www.moneyhouse.ch/u/pub/credit_suisse_ag_CH-020.3.923.549-1.htm#04.05.1998'" href="/u/pub/credit_suisse_ag_CH-020.3.923.549-1.htm#04.05.1998">14 Jahre (04.05.1998)</a></td>
                  <td>-</td>
          <td align="center"></td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to read a local file in `JSoup` you would need to use the [parse method that takes a `File` object](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) rather than the one that takes HTML content. Replace

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("C:\\...\\myFile.html", "UTF-8");
```

with

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new File("C:\\...\\myFile.html"), "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you reading your document?
If it is just a string, then you need to convert it to the "Document" first
You can try something like this:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(YOUR_STRING);
Elements elements = document.getElementsByTag("table");
Element table = elements[0];
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply. I have tried that, doesnt work either unfortunately.. I think the problem is that it appears to be a "TextNode" within the Body-Tag, and not an Element.. so everything inside the Body-Tag is a String..

Comment: I actually do that, unless I did missunderstand you, this is how I parse my html File:

`Document doc = Jsoup.parse("C:\\...\\myFile.html", "UTF-8");`

Comment: Ok, let me test it on my computer

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I appreciate it!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't replicate this issue on my computer. My code can find the table using the same file as you do. But I'm getting the file using a different method and then pass it as a String to the parser. Check if it works for you

Comment: problems has been solved, thanks a lot for your effort, please see the answer above!

Comment: elements[0] will give you: *The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Elements*